# Python FPDF ignore Header and Footer in cover page

Tags: python, fpdf

I have created a pdf file with FPDF in python. i use a header and footer and call them with "add_page". my first page is a cover page. is there an elegant way to ignore the header in the first page?

Any help will be appreciated!

```
from fpdf import FPDF
class PDF(FPDF):
    # Page footer
    def footer(self):
        # Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        self.set_y(-15)
        # Arial italic 8
        self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
        # Page number
        self.cell(0, 10, 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()) + '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C')

# Instantiation of inherited class
pdf = PDF()
pdf.alias_nb_pages()
##Page 1
pdf.add_page()

##Page 2
pdf.add_page()

pdf.output('tuto2.pdf', 'F')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve this by adding a conditional statement for the header and footer. Example of conditional footer below:

```
class PDF(FPDF):
    # Page footer
    def footer(self):
        # Do not print footer on first page 
        if self.page_no() != 1:
            # Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
            self.set_y(-15)
            # Arial italic 8
            self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
            # Page number
            self.cell(0, 10, 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()) + '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C')
```

Comment: hi mechanical_meat. works perfect  - you made my day

Comment: @Alex: cheers, mate. Have a great rest of today :)

Comment: looks like not many people are using fpdf. may you have a solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318317/create-pdf-with-fpdf-in-python-can-not-move-image-to-the-right-in-a-loop

Comment: @Alex: truth be told, I don't even use `fpdf`. But I provided an answer to that question you linked.

Comment: i  tried so hard and i also tried the code form the documentation... i will buy  you a coffe now. beceause it works. thank you

Comment: @Alex: thank you, you're my first supporter since I just recently set that up! I will always remember your support. I'm glad my solution works for you.

Comment: great to hear! greets alex