# create pdf with fpdf in python. can not move image to the right in a loop

Tags: python, fpdf

I use FPDF to generate a pdf with python. i have a problem for which i am looking for a solution. in a folder "images", there are pictures that I would like to display each on ONE page. I did that - maybe not elegant. unfortunately i can't move the picture to the right. it looks like pdf_set_y won't work in the loop.

```
from fpdf import FPDF

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('../images') if isfile(join('../images', f))]


pdf = FPDF('L')
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)

onlyfiles = ['VI 1.png', 'VI 2.png', 'VI 3.png']
y = 10

for image in onlyfiles:
    pdf.set_x(10)
    pdf.set_y(y)
    pdf.cell(10, 10, 'please help me' + image, 0, 0, 'L')
    y = y + 210 #to got to the next page

    pdf.set_x(120)
    pdf.set_y(50)
    pdf.image('../images/' + image, w=pdf.w/2.0, h=pdf.h/2.0)

pdf.output('problem.pdf', 'F')
```

Would be great if you have a solution/help for me. Thanks alot
greets alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see the issue. You want to specify the `x` and `y` location in the call to `pdf.image()`. That assessment is based on the documentation for `image` here: https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html

So you can instead do this (just showing `for` loop here):

```
for image in onlyfiles:
    pdf.set_x(10)
    pdf.set_y(y)
    pdf.cell(10, 10, 'please help me' + image, 0, 0, 'L')
    y = y + 210 # to go to the next page

    # increase `x` from 120 to, say, 150 to move the image to the right
    pdf.image('../images/' + image, x=120, y=50, w=pdf.w/2.0, h=pdf.h/2.0)
    #                        new -> ^^^^^  ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme) library. It's the most powerful library in python to create PDF documents. You can add urls, footnotes, headers and footers, tables, anything you would need in a PDF document.

The only problem I see is that currently pdfme only supports jpg format for images. But if that's not a problem it will help you with your task.

Check the docs [here](https://pdfme.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I am the author of `pText` the library I will use in this solution.

Let's start by creating an empty `Document`:

```
pdf: Document = Document()

# create empty page
page: Page = Page()

# add page to document
pdf.append_page(page)
```

Next we are going to load an `Image` using `Pillow`

```
import requests
from PIL import Image as PILImage

im = PILImage.open(
        requests.get(
            "https://365psd.com/images/listing/fbe/ups-logo-49752.jpg", stream=True
        ).raw
    )
```

Now we can create a `LayoutElement` `Image` and use its `layout` method

```
    Image(im).layout(
        page,
        bounding_box=Rectangle(Decimal(20), Decimal(724), Decimal(64), Decimal(64)),
    )
```

Keep in mind the origin (in PDF space) is at the lower left corner.

Lastly, we need to store the `Document`

```
# attempt to store PDF
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as out_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, pdf)
```

You can obtain pText either on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release), or using [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/ptext-joris-schellekens/)
There are a ton more [examples](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md), check them out to find out more about working with images.

Comment: Hi Joris, thanks for your solution. i will have a closer look at it. at the momentent i am not sure if you solution is what i am looking for. because my code is just a part of a bigger code with header, footer , tables etc.